# How to send the postman request to docker containers hello word application?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build the hello word docker image. But I am not able to get any response from POSTMAN GET request. Could you pls help to resolve?

Steps Tried:

1. My hello word program:

[image]

2.My docker file:

[image]

3. my folder structure
   [image]

4.Building image:

[image]

5.Checking image:
[image]

6.Checking docker machine ip:

[image]

7. Create and run the container with docker machine ip

[image]

[image]

8. Checking logs:

[image]

9. Query with post man both local host and docker machine ip. ( No response)

Note: Tried with all options text,JSON,HTML

[image]

[image]

After that I have deleted the container & Tried to create and run with local host ip as below. Still no response from POSTMAN ( docker machine ip & local host ip)

[image]

[image]
[image]

As Ewong suggested  & other form suggested I have modified the  code as below.

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /program

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

copy src/ .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python","./app.py","--host", "0.0.0.0" ]


from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But when i give curl command failed:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code and output as Text and not as images.

Comment: While you're exposing the port 5000,  you're not going to be able to access that system when you have the system listening at ```127.0.0.1:5000```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker image app is listening on 127.0.0.1:5000.  It's going to ignore everything coming in from the external IP.

Change:

```
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

to:

```
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: Hi Ewong,I have update the app.py as you mentioned. How should run the docker? I have used both option to run   e.g  docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 api_testing  and docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000  still i am not able to get POST response.

Comment: You run it the same way.